# Toggling visibility of all divs after certain ID

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to create a print function in Squarespace for a certain text block. To avoid having the adminstrators input code, i want to be able to use the built in WYSIWYG simplicity. However this limits how deep I can code certain elements.

For my Print code what I am doing is inserting a code block above the text and putting a span ID titled Print:

```
<span id="print">Document to print</span>
```

The way that squarespace works is that it nests this in a contained DIV. These are automatically generated, so calling it by certain classes such as `html-block` wont work as there are many different divs of that kind.

```
<div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1534372053149_74057">
  <div class="sqs-block-content">
    <span id="print">Document to print</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sqs-block html-block sqs-block-html" data-block-type="2" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1534372053149_78086">
  <div class="sqs-block-content">
    <p>Printed text line 1</p>
    <p>Printed text line 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what i'm attempting to do is just to classify everything on the page to be hidden, and everything after the `id="print"` to be visible as so:

```
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  } 
  div ~ #print, div ~ #print * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  div ~ #print {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

What this results in is everything is hidden except:

```
<span id="print">Document to print</span>
```

Is there a way to display ALL elements after `#print`

Comment: `data-block-type"2"` should be `data-block-type="2"`.

Comment: You can’t really select accross different parent elements with CSS. It might be possible with [`div:has(#print) ~ div, div:has(#print) ~ div *`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, **no**.

The problem in your example is that `<span id="print">` is nested, and unfortunately, there is **[no parent selector in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)**. Thus, it is impossible to target anything **but** the print element itself in your example with a selector based off of `#print`. You **must** work from parent to child (or subsequent sibling) in terms of CSS selectors.

Having said that, there are a number of different ways to target an element, and you may well find that there's a combination in your DOM that will allow you to target the relevant element. For example, SquareSquare **does** give unique IDs. Does `#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1534372053149_78086` change its position in the DOM? if not, you can target it as above. You could also target based on `.html-block`, or even something like `div[data-block-type="2"]`:

```css
div[data-block-type="2"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1534372053149_74057">
  <div class="sqs-block-content">
    <span id="print">Document to print</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sqs-block html-block sqs-block-html" data-block-type="2" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1534372053149_78086">
  <div class="sqs-block-content">
    <p>Printed text line 1</p>
    <p>Printed text line 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget you can also make use of the **[`::nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)** and **[`::nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)** pseudo-selectors and **[general sibling combinator (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)** if those help target based on preceding elements.

If you have access to JavaScript, things become very easy, as you can simply use **[`.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)** and **[`.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)**:

```js
const print = document.getElementById('print');
const parent = print.parentNode.parentNode;
const after_print = parent.nextElementSibling;

console.log(after_print.id);
```

```html
<div class="sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code" data-block-type="23" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1534372053149_74057">
  <div class="sqs-block-content">
    <span id="print">Document to print</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sqs-block html-block sqs-block-html" data-block-type="2" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1534372053149_78086">
  <div class="sqs-block-content">
    <p>Printed text line 1</p>
    <p>Printed text line 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

_You could also target based on .html-block, or even something like div[data-block-type="2"]:_
Unfortunately this wouldn't work because i have different types of text blocks that all get that `data-type` or class `html-block`; and I have more text blocks on the same page that I don't want to print out. 

I tried to put the javascript in as you mentioned, but when I go to print, it just outputs the whole page in the print preview